# Smarty 'if' statement syntax

Tags: smarty

I have assigned a variable based on the number of characters in a name, which returns an integer (1,2,3, etc).  I would like to further add an {if} statement to show an option if the option name matches the variable.  The option names are **5" x 7" - 1,  5" x 7" - 2,  5" x 7" - 3** etc.

```
{assign var="numberofcharacters" value=$smarty.get.name|count_characters}

{if $vr.variant_name == '5" x 7" - $numberofcharacters' || $vr.variant_name == '8" x 11" - $numberofcharacters'}
...
{/if}
```

This is not producing a result, even though I have 3 options that should be showing.  Please could somebody let me know what is wrong with my {if} statement?

I cannot use:

```
{if $vr.variant_name|contains:}
```

because if the value returned is 1, then 10, 11 and 12 are also included when I just need 1 included.

MANY THANKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smarty3 with escaped quotes:

```
{$numberofcharacters = 1}
{$var = "5\" x 7\" - {$numberofcharacters}"}
{$var}
```

or

```
{$numberofcharacters = 1}
{$name = '5" x 7"'}
{$var = "{$name} - {$numberofcharacters}"}
{$var}
```

or Smarty2

```
{assign var="numberofcharacters" value=1}
{assign var="name" value='5" x 7"'}
{assign var="var" value="`$name` - `$numberofcharacters`"}
{$var}
```

or using the [cat modifier](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.cat.tpl)

```
{assign var="numberofcharacters" value=1}
{assign var="name" value='5" x 7"'}
{assign var="var" value=$name|cat:" - "|cat:$numberofcharacters}
{$var}
```

throwing things together should be easy enough…

```
{$numberofcharacters = 1}
{$five_seven = "5\" x 7\" - {$numberofcharacters}"}
{$eight_eleven = "8\" x 11\" - {$numberofcharacters}"}
{if $vr.variant_name == $five_seven || $vr.variant_name == $eight_eleven}
  …
{/if}
```

But… If you have a fixed pattern you want to check, you might want to use a regular expression instead? or a substr?

```
{$variant_name = '5" x 7" - 123'}
{if preg_match('/^5" x 7"|^8" x 11"/', $variant_name, $tmp)}
  hello world
{/if}
```

(you should do stuff like that in your PHP though…)

Comment: I have Smarty v2.6 and solution #3 works perfectly, thanks Rodney!

Answer (score 0):

Smarty isn't parsing this:

```
'5" x 7" - $numberofcharacters'
```

as you expect.

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.capture.tpl

```
{assign var="numberofcharacters" value=$smarty.get.name|count_characters}
{capture c1 assign=test1}5" x 7" - {$numberofcharacters}{/capture}
{capture c1 assign=test2}8" x 11" - {$numberofcharacters}{/capture}
{if $vr.variant_name==test1 || $vr.variant_name==test2}
    ...
```

Comment: Hi Tim, tried this but not working for me.  VERY many thanks for your help, it's much appreciated as I now have the {capture} function to learn how to use!!!