# How to - If statement on Display Property

Tags: php, smarty

This displays the company logo

```
{display property='Logo' object_sid=$user_sid}
```

However how would I get it to say if they have a logo display it if not dont display something.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: cant understand can you please expalin more.

Comment: `if(condition){ do something } else{...}` http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279588/smarty-if-statement-syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `if-else` statement checks for a given condition at first, if fulfilled moves to the very first part or `else` goes to the other part.

An Example:

```
<?php
    $display_property = "Logo";
if(isset($display_property)){
    echo $display_property;
}else
{
    echo "No display";
}
?>
```

> Note: Given with the Information in your question, this example was
>   created. However this might not do the *EXACT* thing but would play a
>   vital role in understanding what you're struggling with.

[PHP Manual: else-If condition](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Comment: Perfect thank you! Exactly what i needed. Will mark as answered when i can.